# How to replace single value in pandas dataframe by index

Tags: python

Below is an example of what I want to do. Basically I know the index and the column of the value I want to replace and just want to replace a specific cell. No conditional statements.

```py
df_a = pd.DataFrame(data={"a": [0, 0, 0], "b": [0, 0, 0]})
display(df_a)

    a   b
0   0   0
1   0   0
2   0   0

df_b = pd.DataFrame(data={"a": [0, 0, 10], "b": [0, 0, 0]})

    a   b
0   0   0
1   0   0
2   10  0
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting false positives on answer until I found what I wanted on documenting:

```py
df_a = pd.DataFrame(data={"a": [0, 0, 0], "b": [0, 0, 0]})


df_a.at[2, "b"] = 10
display(df_a)

    a   b
0   0   0
1   0   0
2   10  0
```

NOTE: `python df_a.iat[2,1]`  can be used to achieve the same result if wanting to use integer-based column indexes.